# Unknown column '(value)' in 'field list'

Tags: php, mysql, syntax-error

Ok, maybe I am a fool, but I can't find out whats wrong here. :)

I get this error

> Unknown column '(the value user has selected from the dropdown)' in 'field list'

Yes, I know that this question has been asked many times before, and I have tried to fix my problem with the old answers, but I can't figure it out.
I'm trying to make a posting form for a forum and my error is because of the "Select topic type" dropdown menu.

```
 <?php
//create_topic.php
include 'connect.php';
include 'header.php';

echo '<h2>Create a topic</h2>';
if($_SESSION['signed_in'] == false)
{
    //the user is not signed in
    echo 'Sorry, you have to be <a href="/forum/signin.php">signed in</a> to create a topic.';
}
else
{
    //the user is signed in
    if($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] != 'POST')
    {   
        //the form hasn't been posted yet, display it
        //retrieve the categories from the database for use in the dropdown
        $sql = "SELECT
                    cat_id,
                    cat_name,
                    cat_description
                FROM
                    categories";

        $result = mysql_query($sql);

        if(!$result)
        {
            //the query failed, uh-oh :-(
            echo 'Error while selecting from database. Please try again later.';
        }
        else
        {
            if(mysql_num_rows($result) == 0)
            {
                //there are no categories, so a topic can't be posted
                if($_SESSION['user_level'] == 1)
                {
                    echo 'You have not created categories yet.';
                }
                else
                {
                    echo 'Before you can post a topic, you must wait for an admin to create some categories.';
                }
            }
            else
            {

                echo '<form method="post" action="">
                    Subject: <input type="text" name="topic_subject" /><br />
                    Category:'; 

                echo '<select name="topic_cat">';
                    while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result))
                    {
                        echo '<option value="' . $row['cat_id'] . '">' . $row['cat_name'] . '</option>';
                    }
                echo '</select><br />
                <select name="topic_type">
                <option value="Q&A">Q&A</option>
                <option value="Development">Development</option>
                <option value="Rooting and tweeking">Rooting and tweeking</option>
                <option value="Other">Other</option>
                </select><br />';   

                echo 'Message: <br /><textarea name="post_content" /></textarea><br /><br />
                    <input type="submit" value="Create topic" />
                 </form>';
            }
        }
    }
    else
    {
        //start the transaction
        $query  = "BEGIN WORK;";
        $result = mysql_query($query);

        if(!$result)
        {
            //Damn! the query failed, quit
            echo 'An error occured while creating your topic. Please try again later.';
        }
        else
        {

            //the form has been posted, so save it
            //insert the topic into the topics table first, then we'll save the post into the posts table
            $sql = "INSERT INTO 
                        topics(topic_subject,
                               topic_date,
                               topic_cat,
                               topic_by,
                               topic_type)
                   VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                               NOW(),
                               " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                               " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ",
                               " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_type']) . "
                               )";

            $result = mysql_query($sql);
            if(!$result)
            {
                //something went wrong, display the error
                echo 'An error occured while inserting your data. Please try again later.<br /><br />' . mysql_error();
                $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);
            }
            else
            {
                //the first query worked, now start the second, posts query
                //retrieve the id of the freshly created topic for usage in the posts query
                $topicid = mysql_insert_id();

                $sql = "INSERT INTO
                            posts(post_content,
                                  post_date,
                                  post_topic,
                                  post_by,
                                  post_type)
                        VALUES
                            ('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_content']) . "',
                                  NOW(),
                                  " . $topicid . ",
                                  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . "
                                  " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['post_type']) . ",
                            )";
                $result = mysql_query($sql);

                if(!$result)
                {
                    //something went wrong, display the error
                    echo 'An error occured while inserting your post. Please try again later.<br /><br />' . mysql_error();
                    $sql = "ROLLBACK;";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);
                }
                else
                {
                    $sql = "COMMIT;";
                    $result = mysql_query($sql);

                    //after a lot of work, the query succeeded!
                    echo 'You have succesfully created <a href="topic.php?id='. $topicid . '">your new topic</a>.';
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

include 'footer.php';
?>
```

**Table structure**

*posts*

Kolonne Type    Null    Standard    Kommentarer
post_id int(8)  Nei
post_content    text    Nei
post_date   datetime    Nei
post_topic  int(8)  Nei
post_by int(8)  Nei
post_type   varchar(255)    Nei

*topics*

Kolonne Type    Null    Standard    Linker til  Kommentarer
topic_id    int(8)  Nei
topic_subject   varchar(255)    Nei
topic_date  datetime    Nei
topic_cat   int(8)  Nei         categories -> cat_id
topic_by    int(8)  Nei
topic_type  varchar(100)    Nei

(In Norwegian, but I think you will understand)
Thanks :)

Comment: The error really says `'(my value here)'`?

Comment: It means your column names don't match the table definition. Since you haven't given a minimized example, difficult to help you beyond that.

Comment: No, but the value is depending on what the user selects from the dropdown menu :) I will edit it

Comment: can we have table structure here .

Comment: which line in the above code actually produces this error?

Comment: it seems that you are dealing with referential integrity (maybe innodb). Is it possible that there is something wrong configured in your db? does it work if you manually insert some data for example with phpmyadmin?

Comment: maybe you should show us the complete result of "show create table [tablename]" of table posts, topics and categories

Answer (score 1, accepted):

by the way...

topic_type seems to be a string so you should put in quotes in your insert query:

```
 $sql = "INSERT INTO 
           topics(topic_subject,
                   topic_date,
                   topic_cat,
                   topic_by,
                   topic_type)
          VALUES('" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_subject']) . "',
                  NOW(),
                  " . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_cat']) . ",
                  " . $_SESSION['user_id'] . ",
                  '" . mysql_real_escape_string($_POST['topic_type']) . "'
          )";
```

Maybe thats the reason for your errror.

I saw post_type is a string, too. So do the same in the second insert query!